# For loop with unwanted excess columns

Tags: java

I am getting unwanted extra columns from this set of codes. I just want to add 0 for data that doesn't match but it provides me with all the columns of data and indicate 0 and 1 respectively.

```
for ( int i = 0 ; i < GST.size(); i++)
    {           
        for ( String FLD: GHA.keySet() )
        {
            if ( GHA.get(FLD).containsKey(  GST.get(i)  ) )
                GHAS.get(FLD).append("1,");
            else //these 2 lines
                GHAS.get(FLD).append("0,"); //these 2 lines
        }
    }

    String resultString =  stringWriter.toString();

    for ( String FLD: GHA.keySet() )
        resultString += FLD+ "," +GHAS.get(FLD).toString() + System.getProperty("line.separator");
```

**Here's an output of this code**

```
row1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0
row2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
row3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1
row4, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0
row5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
```

**Without the 2 lines which i've indicated it would be**

```
row1, 1,
row2, 
row3, 1,
row4, 1,
row5,
```

**My desired output is**

```
row1, 1,
row2, 0,
row3, 1,
row4, 1,
row5, 0,
```

Comment: Can you add the definition of all the objects you use here? (GHA, GST, GHAS...)

Comment: What is GST, GHA, GHAS and myGTD? What is the problem you are trying to solve? What is this code supposed to do? It's unclear what you are asking.

Comment: @tavo GST is an array of data. GST and GHAS is a variable in my hashmap.

Comment: Still, can you post their definitions? 
"A variable in my hashmap" 
or
"an array of data"
does not tell me their types.

Comment: @JaroslawPawlak myGTD was a typo from my previous tries. This was suppose to convert my file into .CSV files and I am trying to deal with the output display in the .CSV file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
for ( String FLD: GHA.keySet() )
    {
        boolean appended = false;           
        for ( int i = 0 ; i < GST.size(); i++)
        {
            if ( GHA.get(FLD).containsKey(  GST.get(i)  ) ) {
                GHAS.get(FLD).append("1,");
                appended = true;
                // optionally break here if you don't want multiple 1s
            }

        }
        if (!appended) {
            GHAS.get(FLD).append("0,"); // instead of those 2 lines
        }
    }

    String resultString =  stringWriter.toString();

    for ( String FLD: GHA.keySet() )
        resultString += FLD+ "," +GHAS.get(FLD).toString() + System.getProperty("line.separator");
```

Comment: `GHAS.get(FLD).append("0,");` FLD is not visible here.

Comment: Did you realize the inner for loop appends to different objects?